# Behaviour of rolling_mean

Tags: pandas

When using pandas [`stats.moments.rolling_mean(array,window)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.stats.moments.rolling_mean.html) function I noticed that putting an extra argument changes the output, and is only padded with `nans` in the beginning not the end.

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd

In[2]: pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(np.arange(12),6)
Out[2]: 
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5,
        8.5])
```

I expected there to be 6 `nan`s: 3 at the beginning and 3 at the end.
What am I missing here?

/M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pandas implementation uses a rolling window of the previous *n* values, which is how it's usually done in finance (see this [Wikipedia entry for simple moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#simple_moving_average)).

I guess it would be nice to have the option to specify whether the values should be taken from either side or just use previous values - you can raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas).

`len(np.arange(12))` and `len(pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(np.arange(12),6))` both equal 12 as I would have expected - what result were you expecting?

Comment: I have faced this with rolling statistics in pandas, too. I'd say for non-time-related measurements, such as an altitude vs. distance profile, a central-based moving window makes more sense, since it does not introduce lag or shift. Now for time-based measurements, I think taking only previous values makes more sense, since it would be conceptually wrong if "future" values influenced present ones.

Comment: The actual function implementation is around line 949 of this file: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/algos.pyx. It's relatively comfortable to see that it is implemented at a pretty low level.

Comment: Sorry for the late post here. My data is relative humidity time series but the data has repeating aliasing effects that creates a "saw-like" curve instead of a smooth one. I used the pandas function and the results matched what I could create myself: a smooth curve that takes the mean of the first 6 points and the following 6 points. Of course you can specify the lag and lead times. The results looks very good. Thanks for your help.